# Are there any Ebook libraries in UAE?

Tags: library, united-arab-emirates

Are there any Ebook libraries in UAE or more specifically in Ras Al Khaimah?

Comment: Removed 'Is anyone interested in starting one?' this part of the question is out of scope for the QA part of this site. You can talk about it in chat.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure if it will work where you live. But Google libgen
Maybe you can change your region if it doesn't work there.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you don't have any option in RAK. There are two options:

1. University of Ras Al Khaimah Library has a collection of 300,000 ebooks. You can check more details here
   https://www.aurak.ac.ae/life-at-aurak/library
2. You can become member of libraries in Dubai and Abu Dhabi and you could be eligible to use their elibrary remotely.